# how to get touches began, moved, and ended actions in a scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

i have a uiscrollview with a list of images. if i touches an image it should get the location touched on scrollview and likewise for touches moved and ended.
I did the same process for UIView. but it wont works for scrollview. Guide me